# Dacpac publish how to ignore create database statement?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, dacpac, azure-synapse, dbup

Due to shared database, we don't have admin privs. Only we have schema id.
In dacpac build or sqlpackage.exe  publish is there anyway to ignore the Create database statement ?

2020-03-23T21:48:54.5875811Z ##[error]*** Could not deploy package.
2020-03-23T21:48:54.5930784Z ##[error]Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1 CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE DATABASE [$(Datab
2020-03-23T21:48:54.6200608Z ##[error]aseName)] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

i tried with below option in sqlpackage.exe and it's not working

/p:CreateNewDatabase=False /p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions;Credentials;DatabaseScopedCredentials

is it possible to hack the dacpac sql script comment the create database and from next version it should able to skip because of incremental load? Appreciate your idea.

For Azure sql datawarehouse is there any alternative to DACPAC deployment ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sqlpackage.exe to generate update scripts ([/a:Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#script-parameters-and-properties)) between your dacpac and target database. Then you can remove unneeded instruction. Here is example to create pipeline: [Azure Pipelines - Generating DB Script with SqlPackage.exe](http://diegogiacomelli.com.br/azure-pipelines-generating-db-script/)

Comment: Required automated deployment for future release. If i do as one time sql script removing create database, on second deployment can i use dacpac deployment and it will apply only incremental schema objects changes?